# JQuery: Select is populated but displayed text is old

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a drop down box (select) where user selects certain professor. After that AJAX request gets JSON data from server and populates another drop down box with subjects of that professor. The second drop down box populates without any problem. But the text from the old value ("Please select the professor first!") in second drop down box, that is now not even anymore in drop down box is still being displayed as the default choice after the second drop down box populates.

Here is the js:

```
$('#professorCombo').combobox({
            selected: function() {
                validateAllFields();
                var idProfessor = $(this).val();

                var servletUrl = 'GetTeachersServlet?idProfessor=' + idProfessor;

                $.getJSON(servletUrl, function(data) {
                    var subject = $('#subjectCombo');

                    $('option', subject).remove();

                    if (data) {
                        subject.append($("<option/>").val(-1).text("Select subject..."));

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            subject.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
                        });
                    } else {
                        subject.append($("</option/>").val(-1).text("There are no subjects available!"));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

After the the second drop down box populates the default choice should be: "Select subject". If I open drop down box, that is the first choice but the drop down box still shows old text ("Please select the professor first!"). I think I should refresh it somehow. Also the Firebug says that the selected value of drop down box is value with text "Select subjects", which is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the subject combo val to -1, like this:

```
subject.val(-1).attr('selected',true);
```

It seems that you never set the combo to the new values populated, and its retaining the old value.

Comment: Tried this which is a logical solution, but the second drop down still shows old text. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Where did you add the line? It seems that it should be the last thing in your if(data){...} section.

Comment: At first I added it after: subject.append($("<option/>").val(-1).text("Select subject...")); now that you have pointed out I tried to put it after iterating over data but it makes no diffrence.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is how you're setting the value attribute. Maybe instead of .val(-1), try .attr('value', -1);

Comment: You mean like this: subject.append($("<option/>").attr('value', -1).text("Select subject...")); The same thing like before. It is the first item in second drop down list, but the drop down still has old text value as default.

Comment: This is starting to bug me lol, I can't find any reason why it would not update. After work today, i'll create a jsfiddle and see if I can get to the bottom of it. :)